# Why this move construct have not been called?

Tags: c++

I have wrote a useless class, containing move constructor, default constructor and other construct. But this code (useless four(one + two)) didn't call move constructor. By the way, I have another question. Is safe when I delete a null pointer?

```cpp
class useless {
private:
    int len;
    char * p; // address of string
public:
    ~useless();// default deconstruct
    explicit useless(int len);// len construct
    useless(int len, char c);// two argument construct
    useless(useless&& u); //move construct
    useless operator+(const useless& u) const; // operator +
};

useless::useless(int l) {
  len = l;
  p = new char[len];
}

useless::useless(int l, char c) {
  len = l;
  p = new char[len];
  for(int i =0;i<len;i++){
    p[i] = c;
  }
}

useless::useless(useless&& u) {//move construct
  len = u.len;
  p = u.p;
  u.p = nullptr;
  u.len = 0;
}

useless::~useless() {
  delete[] p;
}

useless useless::operator+(const useless &u) const {
  useless re = useless(n + u.n);

  for(int i =0; i < n; i++){
    re.p[i] = p[i];
  }
  for(int i = n;i < re.n; i++){
    re.p[i] = u.p[i - n];
  }
  return re;
}

int main(){
  useless one(2,'x');
  useless two = one; 
  useless four(one + two);
}
```

Comment: The given code does not compile, please fix it.

Comment: First of all was it called or not? You title contradicts you question. Second, why do you think it should be called? May be compiler optimized it in such way that call is not necessary. And lastly, its safe to delete nullptr, BUT I strongly suggest not to use `new`/`delete` in you code and instead use standard containers and smart pointers.

Comment: I have used c++14 and c++17 to run this code.  Both of them did not call move constructor.  The  result of one+two is rvalue. I think it will call move constuctor.@sklott

Comment: The given code is part of the source code. @karastojko

Comment: @liangsun I understand, but please follow the [guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for posting examples.

Comment: @liangsun, if you have more than one question, well... just create two questions. I'm talking about the "null pointer" one. Please search the site for such a question, and if you didn't find it, just create a new one. Please edit your question removing the "null pointer" one.

Comment: Search for "copy elision" and "named return value optimisation".

Comment: @karastojko . Thanks

Comment: Where did you pull n from? should it be len?

Comment: @arundeepchohan yes it should be len